# How to add Facebook comment evaluation feature

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I saw on some FB group an extra feature on comment, up/down arrow icon(in addition to classic 'like'/'j'aime' icon) that open a way to say if the comment is relevant or not for the group.

I would like to add this cool feature on my group but I'm unable to find how to do that?

[image: FB comment evaluation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I finally found that this kind of feature is a test driven by Facebook itself. So I Imagine as simple user/admin we have no way to activate this feature today.

src:

- socialmediatoday.com up/down vote experiment [november 2020](https://www.socialmediatoday.com/news/facebook-once-again-experiments-with-up-and-down-votes-for-comments-to-opti/588340/) - [avril 2021](https://www.socialmediatoday.com/news/facebook-tests-updated-up-and-downvoting-for-comments-in-groups/598096/)